# this.value in IE issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a problem with `this.value` in IE(7-9).
I use this code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inputbox").keyup(function(){
      value = this.value;
      $("#searchRe").load("suggestionSearch.php?value=" + value);
    });
});    
</script>
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome, but don't pass "value" to "suggestionSearch.php" in IE. I think `value = this.value` is problem. Please help me :)

NOTE: `.inputbox` is a textbox.

Comment: try use var value = $(this).val();

Comment: Check if the .load() function works fine. Another thing is that you should put a `var` operator before `value` variable!

Comment: @Habibillah: I try but not work!

Comment: @Taai: I put a var before value but not work. .load() works in firefox and chrome well. May this have problem with IE?

Comment: Is the #searchRe an `<input>`?

Comment: your code is perfect for value is perfect,just check by putting value in alert()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code and seems to be working well;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >  
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="inputbox" />
        <div id="searchRe"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js" ></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".inputbox").keyup(function(){
              value = this.value;
              $("#searchRe").load("s.php?value=" + value);
            });
        });    
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my php temporary code (since you haven't specified yours)

```
<?php

    echo $_GET['value'];

?>
```

Could you please give us more information? (what kind of data is returned from php file, for example)

**Edit:**

Replace this

```
$("#searchRe").load("s.php?value=" + value);
```

with this one

```
$("#searchRe").load("s.php?value=" + encodeURIComponent(value));
```

please note the function encodeURIComponent, follow [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

since you are already using jQuery, just try to use jquery to get the value, using this line

```
var value = $(this).val()
```

jQuery handles the arbitrary browser behaviors pretty good.

**EDIT**

here is a quick solution which works on IE, you can modify this for your own needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/FeRsB/

Comment: did you check the variable value at all? run alert(value) or, if you are using a developer plugin such as firebug, check the variable using console.log(value)

Comment: I get value in suggestionSearch.php with $value = $_REQUEST['value']; and echo it, but in IE anything don't echo.

Comment: yes! This works but my problem is PASS value to suggestionSearch.php and echo value in this.

Comment: instead of .load(), use the method $.get() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

$.get("suggestionSearch.php", {value: val}, function(response){
     alert(response);
});​

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an element with `id = "value"` on your page? In that case, IE will create a global variable named `value` for it and refuse to assign the global variable value to something else.

If this is what's happening, the solution is as simple as

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".inputbox").keyup(function(){
            var value = this.value;
            $("#searchRe").load("suggestionSearch.php?value=" + value);
        });
    });    
</script>
```

(note the **var** in front of `value`). This is what you should do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can ride the event and use it to obtain needed data. Here is a sample code:

```
<input class="inputbox" type="text" value="-default-" />


<script>

function changeHandler(event) {
    console.log("changeHandler: ",event.target.value);
}
function keyPressHandler(event) {
    console.log("keyPressHandler: ",event.target.value);
}
function keyDownHandler(event) {
    console.log("keyDownHandler: ",event.target.value);
}
function keyUpHandler(event) {
    console.log("keyUpHandler: ",event.target.value);
}
$(function(){
    $(".inputbox")
        .on("change",{},changeHandler)
        .on("keypress",{},keyPressHandler)
        .on("keydown",{},keyDownHandler)
        .on("keyup",{},keyUpHandler);
})
</script>
```

console result after focusing the input field and single press of key "s":

```
    LOG: keyDownHandler: -default- 
    LOG: keyPressHandler: -default- 
    LOG: keyUpHandler: -default-s 
    LOG: changeHandler: -default-s
```

So desired data can be obtained via the event itself (plus any additional if needed as the second {} param when binding the events.

note: "change" event is fired after input field actually is blurred (focus is lost).

p.s. your "onkyeup" handler might be like this:

```
    function(event){
            $("#searchRe")
                  .load("suggestionSearch.php?value=" + event.target.value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the request parameter as an arguement instead of modifying the URL.

```
//                        arguement ----------v
$("#searchRe").load("suggestionSearch.php", {value: this.value});
```

**Full Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".inputbox").keyup(function(){
       $("#searchRe").load("suggestionSearch.php", {value: this.value});
   });
});
```

Also make sure ajax `cache` is set to `false`,

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".inputbox").keyup('', function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("#searchRe").load("suggestionSearch.php?value=" + value);
        });
    });    
</script>
```

I just added the `Event Data` (Probably didn't need, who knows), declared the `var value` and changed the way to get the value to `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue you want append instead of load

```
 StrTemp  = "<ul>"
 $.each(function(value){
  StrTemp += "<li><a id='" + value + "'>" + value + "</a></li>";
 })
 StrTemp += "</ul>"
 $("#searchRe").append(StrTemp);
```

this code work in IE and other

Best Regards

Answer (score -2):

you can also alert($(this).serialize());

Comment: serilalize() is used to serlize form inputs..and create a standard URL-encoded notation, this has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: alert this.value in IE browser

Comment: @Narendra Patel: I get value in suggestionSearch.php with $value = $_REQUEST['value']; and echo it, but in IE anything don't echo.